# Buddypress shortcode for tabs

Tags: shortcode, buddypress

I want to add some more tabs like photos, videos on the user profiles of my buddypress site.

Is there any shortcodes or functions to add the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code,

```
function custom_add_activity_tab() { ?>

  <li id="custom-tab">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url( BP_ACTIVITY_SLUG . '/' ) ?>" title="<?php _e( 'Tab.', 'buddypress' ) ?>">
        <?php printf( __( 'tab' , 'buddypress' ) ); ?>
    </a>
  </li>

<?php }
add_action( 'bp_activity_type_tabs', 'custom_add_activity_tab' );
```

Check it, Will work better

Comment: There is no shortcode available, so try to write functions.

Comment: Now tab is displaying but, how to show content in this tab?